# How to get the content of a secured remote xml file to work with in Wordpress?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, amazon-web-services

there is a xml-file on a remote server. It is updated daily.
I now need to access this file to work with it.

How I access the file via browser:

1. Go to http:// example. com /things.xml *(had to include the spaces because I need a reputation of 10 to post two urls)*
2. Get a "authentication required"-window and put in username and password
3. Get redirected to "https://example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xml/things.xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJUMHKU8TN5SZCU7A&Signature=LgKnfe668s3diBdRSpUnK1sBOL4%3D&Expires=1424967686"
4. See rendering of XML by browser

I tried `file_get_contents('username:password@http://example.com/things.xml')` and get following output:

> E_WARNING : type 2 --
>   file_get_contents(username:password@http://example.com/things.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

Even if I would be able to access the file there would be the problem of getting the contents to work inside Wordpress.

My goal is to display a list of "things".

Thank you in advance
(very first post. Hope I haven't made a lot of mistakes)

Mightvision